# About Python *args

Tags: python, args

```
import math

def square(*args):
    return math.pow(args,2)

a=[]

for i in range(1,101):

    a.append(i)

print(list(map(square,a)))
```

Is there something wrong about this code? I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

Comment: `args` is a tuple

Comment: What output were you expecting? Given that you only pass one parameter, why use `*args` (which handles arbitrary numbers of parameters) at all?

Comment: i am expecting that square all of my numbers which i gave i mean list 
i used *args cause of i want to square many numbers  am i wrong ?

Comment: `map` passes one value from `a` at a time to `square`

Comment: Thank you so much guys i did not know that map passes one value i got it Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

As @heemayl mentioned in the comments, `args` is a tuple. Therefore, to access a single element of the tuple you need to use an indexer:

```
def square(*args):
    return math.pow(args[0], 2)
```

Alternatively, if you are only providing one argument you can pass it straight through with the need to unpack a tuple:

```
def square(x):
    return math.pow(x, 2)
```